# Cant fire my event from the same class

Tags: c#, events, raise

So I have looked at many places and what I am trying to do is not working, although I seem to be doing what everywhere else says I should. I have the following:

```
    private EventHandler statsUpdated;
    public event EventHandler StatsUpdated
    {
        add
        {
            if (statsUpdated == null || !statsUpdated.GetInvocationList().Contains(value))
            {
                statsUpdated += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            statsUpdated -= value;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnStatsUpdated(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler Handler = StatsUpdated;
    }
```

I havent started doing any more to the OnStatsUpdated method yet, as the line in there is erroring saying that StatsUpdated can only be on the left of += or -=. However, I am accessing it from the same class? The above is a direct copy paste, they sit directly together in code right now.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your last line, shouldn't it be: `EventHandler Handler = statsUpdated;` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is typo mistake. Just change last line to `EventHandler Handler = statsUpdated;`

Answer (score 0):

In fact you are not firing the event. To Fire it, you should use

```
protected virtual void OnStatsUpdated(EventArgs e)
{
   var handler = statsUpdated;
   if (handler != null)
      handler (this, e);
}
```

If you're using C# 6 you can simplify it to

```
protected virtual void OnStatsUpdated(EventArgs e)
{
   statsUpdated?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```